# Using python inside Kepler worfklow

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to use the Kepler workflow model and run python scripts inside of it. I am having a hard time importing modules like numpy, json etc.

I have googled this but haven't really found any solutions.

My python scripts are simple and just import numpy and perform an operation with numpy.

Do any of you guys know how I can use these models inside the kepler environment? Would it involve downloading these modules inside the area where Kepler is installed again(even though they are already available on my computer)?

Thanks.

Comment: Numpy does not work with Jython (see https://scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython-or-c-net). Many questions have been asked about that here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh okay. Do you know if it is possible to somehow extract information from an html document in Kepler with python?

Comment: I am not familiar with Kepler, but yes Python can be used to extract information from HTML.

Comment: Yes I too know how to do that in python, but I am trying to implement this in Kepler. Thanks for the help, though.